# Show more shipping option after shipping method selected woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have shipping method named "Pickup From shop" in woocommerce. I want user to show some more fields when my shipping method is selected.

For example, when user select the my shipping "Pickup From shop", I want to show lists of shops and one text box to enter the date.

I have currently done using the modifying the review-template, is this correct way to do this? If not please suggest. Thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_locate_template',array($this, 'wp_pkpo_templates'), 20, 5 );




public function wp_pkpo_templates($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
        global $product;


        if (strstr($template, 'review-order.php')) {
            //Look within passed path within the theme - this is priority

            $template = locate_template(
                    array(
                        WPPKPO_PLUGIN_DIR . '/templates/checkout/review-order.php',
                        $template_name
                    )
            );

            //Get default template

            if (!$template) {


                $template = WPPKPO_PLUGIN_DIR . '/templates/frontend/checkout-map-section.php';
            }
        }

        return $template;
    }
```